# Razor.Parse alternative

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

We have a default value for a textbox that is coming from a database and it is

```
@UserSession.NumberOfPeople
```

This is currently parsed by using

```
string value = Razor.Parse(Model.DefaultValue)
```

Which returns me the string value from that variable

However as `Razor.Parse` is now obsolete, I was looking into an alternative way using `Engine.Razor.Compile` but I can't seem to find an overload that isn't requiring a template

Is there a way of just parsing the the value as it is

```
string value = Razor.Parse("@UserSession.NumberOfPeople")
```

Or do I need to create some sort of template or install a nuget package for this?

Comment: "parsing the the value straight out of the db" what do you mean straight from the db? Why doesn't the Controller provide the data to the View?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto We are using Kentico and it has a default value field in which we enter the string `@UserSession.NumberOfPeople`  this is then read into the `Model.DefaultValue` which is then parsed as above in a partial

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`RazorEngine`](https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/) and simply use your string as the template:

```
Engine.Razor.RunCompile(Model.DefaultValue, "templateKey", null, Model);
```

NOTE: For the `RunCompile` to accept a `string` as a template you need to use `RazorEngine.Templating` (`@using RazorEngine.Templating` in your view).

Comment: Awesome this works like a charm and as it turns out I RazorEngine was already installed on the project.  Ta

Comment: Have you got any trick how to avoid to give unique templateKey?