# Razor.Parse error during parsing googlemap link

Tags: c#, html, parsing, razor

**Scenario**

In my app I parse text, links and tags to `HTML` using `Razor.Parse<>().`

```
string Razor.Parse<TEmail>(string razorTemplate, TEmail model) where TEmail : BaseEmail
```

I use `'@'` to parse data from `model`. I also parse web links. This feature works fine, till I parse `Google Map` links e.g.

**Problem**
https://www.google.com/maps/place/New+York,+NY,+USA/@40.6974034,-74.1197634,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x89c24fa5d33f083b:0xc80b8f06e177fe62!8m2!3d40.7127753!4d-74.0059728
Link includes '**@**'. So I get error:

```
RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateParsingException: '"40.6974034" is not valid at the start of a code block.  Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.'
```

**My try**

I try to parse html with dobule **@@** 
*https://www.google.com/maps/place/New+York,+NY,+USA/@@40.6974034,-74.1197634,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x89c24fa5d33f083b:0xc80b8f06e177fe62!8m2!3d40.7127753!4d-74.0059728* 
But i get error:

```
RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateParsingException: '"@" is not valid at the start of a code block.  Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.'
```

Any idea what can I do? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are trying to pass something that is invalid. when you use the "@" keyword you cannot pass values, you must pass an identifier, keyword, comment, "(", "{". The "@" keyword marks the beginning of a code block for example:

```
string value = Razor.Parse("@UserSession.NumberOfPeople")
```

The above will work but this:

```
string value = Razor.Parse("@http://www.something.com")
```

won't work, this is invalid.

What you need to do is find an alternative. 
you need to use [razor engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48501346/razor-parse-alternative). If you have no idea it is, 
read [here](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=razorengine). You cannot esacpe **@**, because Razor.parse does not escape strings.

Comment: I know it! I tried to escape @ by dobule it (@@) Look at googleMap links. It should work when I escape, but seems not. I do not know why.

Comment: because razor.parse do not escape strings.

Comment: So how do do it :/? I cannot use Html.Raw("@") because it is in c# code and HTML is not available.

Comment: just use the links I provided above and see if it will assist you :)

Comment: I have installed RazorEngine and tried to use: 
htmlBody = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(null, "templateKey", null, email);
Of course i have namespaces: 
using RazorEngine.Templating;
using RazorEngine
But it seems that VisualStudio does not see "Engine"

Comment: check your reference again, see if the namespace exists properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174167/discussion-between-zolty13-and-barr-j).